# Extension method on ICollection<T> doesn't change the calling list?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, icollection

I want to create an extension method that runs on a List and accept another list:

```
public static void Charge<T, S>(this ICollection<T> targetList, ICollection<S> sourceList) where T : class, new()
        {
            if (targetList == null || sourceList == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            targetList = new List<T>();
            foreach (var item in sourceList)
            {
                T t = new T();
                //do work on t
                targetList.Add(t);
            }

        }
```

however when I call it like this:

```
var targetList = new List<Item>();
targetList.Charge(sourceList);
```

the `targetList` doesn't change (items count = 0)

Comment: Remove `targetList = new List<T>();`

Comment: Why do you do `targetList = new List<T>();`?

Comment: You aren't returning the target list, neither are you handling it as a reference.

Comment: I want to make sure it's empty list

Comment: What about `ICollection.Clear()`

Comment: If you want to make sure it's empty, why not just clear the items out of it?

Comment: What do you expect to get when your method returns void?

Comment: Why do you want someone to pass in an empty collection in the first place?  Just don't have the caller provide the collection to begin with and just return a new collection.

Comment: @maccettura return nothing

Comment: I agree with @Servy. I wouldn't even bother passing the target list as a parameter.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed so modify a list and then do nothing with it?  Think about that, do you _really_ think that is what you want?

Comment: Related: [How can I get an extension method to change the original object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2326734) and [Impossible to use ref and out for first (“this”) parameter in Extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2618597).

Comment: Isn't this entire method just a complicated way to not call IEnumerable<T>.Select()?

Answer (score 0):

The proposed method makes no sense to me.

You want to copy the contents of the source list into the target, but you first want to *replace* the target list to make sure it's empty?  If you're going to replace the target list anyway, why not simply replace it like so?

```
target = source.ToList();
```

Also, how do you propose to implement the "do some work on `t`" in a generic extension method where the types of `S` and `T` are not known?  Why not do the idiomatic thing, e.g.:

```
target = source.Select(s => Transform(s)).ToList();
```

Here, we assume `Transform` is a method capable of creating and populating a target object from a source object.

Or, you could avoid reallocating a new list by clearing the old one first:

```
target.Clear();
target.AddRange(source.Select(s => Transform(s)));
```

And if you *really* want to have a single invocation, you could simply wrap either of the alternatives above, e.g.:

```
public static List<TTarget> ToList<TSource, TTarget>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TTarget> conversion)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (conversion == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(conversion));

    return source.Select(conversion).ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
target = source.ToList(s => Transform(s));
```

Comment: Re: just calling ToList(): As I understand it, the problem with that is that the OP's source list is a different T than the target list. Really, IMO, I don't see why the entire code isn't something like var newThings = oldThings.Select(thing => ConvertOldThingToNewThing(thing));

Comment: No worries. It honestly took me longer than I'd have liked to have just come to the realization that this is really just an weirdly-engineered Select() call with a transform.

Answer (score -1):

You can't assign a new instance to `targetList` if you pass the list *by value*. You can add or remove or modify the content of the existing list, but if you want to assign another instance you need to add the `ref` keyword to allow assignments.

Comment: You can not mark `this` argument of extension method with `ref`.

Comment: I know that. But since both are Collections you could swap arguments `public static void Charge<T, S>(this ICollection<S> sourceList, ref ICollection<T> targetList)`